# How to do application event log search using grep?

Tags: windows, grep

I want to search a string in Windows Application Event Logs using Grep.
The following is the log excerpts:

```
I  05-Nov-14 10:08:04   51033   AP_AN           <I>1 images out of 1 are     transferred to ABS_Dynamics for the job(297.0.0) at the rate of 0.09 images / sec.    </I>
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:04, Line: 1068, File: \EdCom\src\ArcNet\ArcNet_server\src\ANBeServer/ANBeNetworkNodeJob_haz.cpp, Process: CGenericMain (7804)
W  05-Nov-14 10:08:53   14  AXY_ISC           State Manager has detected a hung process.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:53, Process: C:\AIOM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:08:53) IV SET: CProcess::DeclareHung(AppUI_A,6228) Process appears to be hung. (null
W  05-Nov-14 10:08:53   17  AXY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:53, Process: C:\AIOM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:08:53) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessFailing(PID:6228 TID:4264) Process AppUI_A is
```

I want to search a string say "CProcess::DeclareHung" in the event logs and the search output should be the following:

```
W  05-Nov-14 10:08:53   14  AXY_ISC           State Manager has detected a hung process.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:53, Process: C:\AIOM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:08:53) IV SET: CProcess::DeclareHung(AppUI_A,6228) Process appears to be hung. (null
```

ie. the logs and the summary lines including the search string.

Each line is delimited by new line character and this log file is a .txt file.
I know that grep is a line based search application , but, I have read that using pearl regular expression , we can make grep to search multi line. I am new to pearl regular expression and don't have a least idea how to do this.

Can anyone help me to search this using grep?

EDIT: I have tried the following, without success

```
grep -P "[W|E|I]  \d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d.*[\s]*.*CProcess::DeclareHung.*[\s]*.*" XA2014_11_04_AppEventLog.txt
```

Comment: what defines a summary lines? Does it always contain a single letter in the very beginning?

Comment: @ fedorqui:The line start with W or I or E will be the log line followed by 0 or more summary lines. All log and summary lines are delimited by new line character. Log lines always contains single letter at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to check what is not in the header, but in the error message, you can say:

```
awk -v RS="\n(E|I|W)" '/CProcess/' file
```

The pity here is that you lose the E/I/W. If you want it, say `awk -v RS="\n(E|I|W)" '/CProcess/ {print RT, $0}' file`.

A more rudimentary approach is to keep a buffer with the block and print it whenever we find a match:

```
awk '$1~/^(E|I|W)$/ {line=$0;next} {line=line ORS $0} /pattern/ {print line}' file
```

That is:

```
awk '$1~/^(E|I|W)$/ {line=$0;next} # if 1st file starts with E,I,W, initialize the
                                # variable line with the content of this line
                                # then, jump to the next line

    {line=line ORS $0}          # on the rest of cases, keep adding the following
                                # lines in the variable line
                                # ORS stands for new line normally

    /pattern/ {print line}'     # if the current line matches the given pattern
                                # print the stored variable `line`
    file
```

Similar logic to print the match no matter where it is found in the text:

```
awk '{if ($1~/^(E|I|W)$/)
      {
        if (print_match) {
            print line
            print_match=0
        }
        line=$0
      } else 
        line=line ORS $0
     }
    /An error/ {print_match=1}
    END {if (print_match) print line}' file
```

Note the usage of a flag `print_match` to know if the buffered line needs to be printed or not. Also the usage of `END` to print it if it was the last block of the file.

---

Test with "CProcess" for your given sample:

```
awk -v RS="\n(E|I|W)" '/CProcess/' file
  05-Nov-14 10:08:53   14  AXY_ISC           State Manager has detected a hung process.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:53, Process: C:\AIOM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:08:53) IV SET: CProcess::DeclareHung(AppUI_A,6228) Process appears to be hung. (null
```

And

```
$ awk '$1~/^(E|I|W)$/ {line=$0;next} {line=line ORS $0} /CProcess/ {print line}' file
W  05-Nov-14 10:08:53   14  AXY_ISC           State Manager has detected a hung process.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:08:53, Process: C:\AIOM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:08:53) IV SET: CProcess::DeclareHung(AppUI_A,6228) Process appears to be hung. (null
```

Comment: This is to develop an additional feature for my tool. And I am using grep for all kind of log search in my tool. Isn't there any way to use grep instead of awk to achieve the output?

Comment: I think that sticking to one tool is not useful if another one provides better performance. Here `grep` would be overly complicated (`grep -C2 "..."` or similar and then piping to get the desired output).

Comment: Could you please help on using Grep?

Comment: Finally I decided to use awk in my tool. :). But when I tried the command you have suggested, it is showing errors as following:    

    awk '$1~/^(E|I|W)$/ {line=$0;next} {line=line ORS $0} /CProcess/ {print line}' d:\res.txt
'I' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Smij01 uhms, strange. Could you update your question and paste exactly what you are running? Also useful to indicate what awk version you use.

Comment: I have figured out that in windows I have to use "(double quote) instead of '(single quote) along with awk. So I replaced ' in your command with " . Now the error is vanished, but not printing anything.
This is what I have tried: awk "$1~/^(E|I|W)$/ {line=$0;next} {line=line ORS $0}  /CProcess::DeclareHung/ {print line}" XA2014_11_04_AppEventLog.txt

Comment: @Smij01 no, using double quotes is not the solution, because then `$1` will be seen as a bash variable instead of an awk one.

Comment: Then what is the solution? I am quite a new comer to awk. Do you have any solution for this because if I don't use '(single quote) , it will show "  'I' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Smij01 as I said before, please indicate what exact version of awk you are using, the input file and the exact command you are using. Why? Because the command I posted works fine to me, so I have to know what is the difference in your side.

Comment: @feqorqui: My Goodness!! With " , I am able to get the output now. I was using a pattern which was not in the file.. Thanks a lot feqorqui.. And one more query: Could you please explaine me how the command works.. As per my understanding $1~/^(E|I|W)$/   ----  matching E|I|W in the first field, {line=$0;next} --- storing current line to 'line' and reading next line... After this I could not understand.. :)

Comment: This solution works for me to some extent. But my actual requirement is that the search string can be in either main log line or summary line. whenever a match found, i want to get that main log line and all the summary lines . With your solution, it is not match with first line and whenever a match found, it omits the following lines after the matching line.

Comment: @Smij01 this I said from the very beginning when mentioning this approach. You can get it working with `awk '{if ($1~/^(E|I|W)$/) {if (print_match) {print 1,line; print_match=0} line=$0} else line=line ORS $0} /An error/ {print_match=1} END {if (print_match) print line}' file`. You may want to use the other approach with RS.

Comment: RS approach omits W|I|E. So I prefer the approach which you have given minutes ago. The solution with If condition , gives the result what I want. Thank you so much for your help. But can you please explain me how this is working? And can you please edit your answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @Smij01 the logic is similar to the one I explained, so you shouldn't have problems to understand it. Updated answer!

Comment: The solution you gave in comments differs the solution you have updated in answer section. The answer section solution gives me error :